# How to start a project

Tags: project-planning

Just wondering how to start a project from concept,specs,dev etc. In development do you start with database design? or maybe theres a resource you know i can look at.

Comment: this is a very open ended question that is going to vary wildly from project to project and team to team.  There really can't be a definitive answer to it.  Maybe one of the other stack exchange sites would be a better fit for this question?

Comment: I've never read it but it sounds like you might be interested in The Art of Start by Guy Kawasaki - http://www.amazon.com/Art-Start-Time-Tested-Battle-Hardened-Starting/dp/1591840562/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1289869199&sr=8-1

Answer (score 1):

Starting with database design is actually a big pet peeve of mine.  Sure, it's fine for some projects.  Simple forms-over-data apps, stuff like that.  But for anything more complex, anything that has a "domain" of logic, do not start with database design.  Start with domain modeling.  If you're taking business logic and putting it in code, then it's highly likely that the business users who define the logic flow do not think in terms of SQL or relational data at rest.  They think in terms of logical interactions of concrete and abstract concepts.

As Eric S. Raymond said, "Smart data structures and dumb code works better than the other way around."  Usually, when one starts with the database design, one creates a flat "dumb" data structure.  Not dumb in the sense that it's a bad design, but in the sense that it has no built-in logic.  It's flat and dimensionless.  All of the intelligence would need to go into the code that uses it.

A rich domain model, on the other hand, incorporates business logic and concepts directly into the data structures.  It's enhances the data itself with actual business intelligence, carrying that intelligence throughout the domain.

Now, this doesn't mean that you shouldn't think of persistence at all while designing the domain.  But the persistence should be built to accompany the domain, not the other way around.  Nilsson suggests starting with the domain and during the development of it take breaks to think and work on the persistence.  This is because the domain model is really the core, but you'll need to evaluate any compromises on persistence to keep yourself realistic.  Going for true persistence ignorance could dig yourself into some holes.

Comment: Good points.  I consider that the step of documenting what the application should do but my comment was less formalized.  A big mistake I've seen over and over is not defining the vocabulary and everyone gets confused because different people use different terms for the same thing.

Comment: @JOTN: Absolutely.  Creating a "domain-specific language" which all participants can understand is a critical early step.  Too many times, business software is developed which doesn't quite do what the business thinks it should.  This puts future developers at odds with the business users because their job is to support the software, and the business put them in front of software that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

That all depends on what sparked the motivation to start a project in the first place.  It could vary from sitting down and fleshing out detains of something that's been brewing amorphously in your mind for years, or sitting down and making a quick and dirty prototype to convince yourself that the genius idea you had that seemed so simple is actually quite a thorny bush that requires you to sit down and flesh out.

I never start with database design, as that's an implementation detail.  I might not even want to use a database.  I start with the functional design.  What do I want it to do?  Why?  How?  How does it do it differently from other approaches?  Is the benefit enough to even bother doing it at all?  You get the idea.  Implementation design is tackled once I know clearly what I am doing and most importantly why.

Answer (score 0):

That is very general but the first step is always to figure out and document what you want the application to do.  Then I usually develop and ERD which defines the tables required to accomplish those functions along with the class structure that sits in front of those tables.  Once those two big parts get done, it's usually pretty smooth sailing.